# Core Data Lightweight Migration back to the beginning

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I'm trying to cleanup my mess with coreData.

History:
- I created a coreData project for iOS
- I successfully initiated a few lightweight migrations, ending up with the xcdatamodeld folder holding numerous xcdatamodel items.
- Since I was just testing, I decided I would like to remove old xcdatamodel items from the folder. I read that deleting them would be fine, and did so.
- After deleting the previous xcdatamodel items, the folder went away, leaving me with my latest xcdatamodel item
- Development continued without the need to migrate and all was happy.

Now:
Today, I tried to perform a lightweight migration on my xcdatamodel item (not a folder).  I quickly noticed that when I performed Editor - Add Model Version... I did not get the dialogue box Version Name... Based on Model...  I just got a create dialogue box.

- I created a Model Version but it crashed stating it could not merge...

What I want:
It appears that I need to somehow convert my lone xcdatamodel item to a xcdatamodeld item... like I started with when I created the project.  I need to be able to perform lightweight migrations like I did back at the beginning.

Can anyone help?